# Fix of err_ssl_protocol_error

Tags: python, ssl, subprocess

[enter image description here][1]I'm currently making a project where I'm opening a browser window using subprocess python. When I specifically use "discord.com" as domain I get "err_ssl_protocol_error" however on other websites such as "kith.com" it works completely fine. I've done a lot of research but haven't found a solution currently working for me. Im using **http** btw. Appreciate any answer!

Ouput:

````
[39402:11779:1207/203238.583590:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(983)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
[39402:11779:1207/203238.606328:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(983)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
[39402:11779:1207/203238.622309:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(983)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
[39402:11779:1207/203239.085249:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(983)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
[39402:11779:1207/203239.086367:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(983)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107```
````

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace and error output (in text form).  A lot of things could cause an SSL error.

Comment: So, I guess the problem is in the browser.  What browser and OS?

Comment: Just made an edit, thank you!

Comment: Chrome, v95 on macOS